# I can't add any Stack Overflow answers to Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I try to add an answer to my Careers profile, it says that I don't have any, but I have answered some questions on Stack Overflow.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your account Id was not set on Careers.  It looks like this happened because you used a different open id to sign up for careers than you used when you signed up for the other sites which would cause this to happen.

I have updated it for you.  Try again and let us know if you can see your stuff now.